# How can I redirect IIS request to a specific url

Tags: windows, iis, deployment

we had an application (http://stellramapps.com/) which was running in server1, now the application has been migrated to server2.
We have done the DNS settings for the request coming to server1 to route to server2.
the IIS redirection rule also has been set with the regular  expression = ^http://stellramapps to redirect to http://tdstest/
but still i face the below error
Can’t reach this page

•Make sure the web address http://stellramapps.com is correct

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

http:// is not included in HTTP_HOST so please try ^stellramapps$ instead of ^http://stellramapps.

Plesease ensure http://tdstest/ can be accessed from the server of stellramapps.

Then please install URL rewrite and ARR

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Finally, you can enable IIS manager->server node->application request routing cache->Server Proxy Settings->Enable Proxy and apply this rule

```
   <rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^stellramapps$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://tdstest/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: I tried, The request is coming till the server IP but it is not navigating to the http://tdstest. Please help!

Comment: @ILYASKHAN Plesae enable failed request tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules